# Auto update a due date based on the last review date

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet I use to maintain when certain policies are due for review.  I have a column (column d) for the last reivew date and a column (column e) for the date the policy is due for review again.  Is there a way I can set column e to automatically add 2 years to whatever the date was in column d?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula: `=DATE(YEAR(D1)+2,MONTH(D1),DAY(D1))`

You can copy the formula down the column by selecting E1, then double-clicking the small black square in the lower-right of the E1 cell.

http://www.mrexcel.com/td0003.html